# ArcGIS - missing old lyr file

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, layer-file

I have some mxds from a few years back that I have been tasked with re-purposing.  I need to recreate the original symbology, now missing, which was apparently done by loading a lyr file from parts unknown.  Is there any way I can tell which lyr file was used to create the symbology?

If I create a legend it pulls the symbology I need, with the proper names & colors, but the source data doesn't contain the basis for this symbology.  What the source data has is a massive field of numbers, which in the lyr file (I assume) were encoded into what I need (ie 174367 = Room X).  I hope I won't have to manually recreate this encoding.

Comment: You are correct with your assessment of what used to be present in the LYR file.  It likely contained the mappings for setting the display text ("room X") based on a feature id or what have you.

Unfortunately LYR files are binary format so it is almost impossible to glean any sort of information out of them without just loading them up one by one onto a layer.  The mapfile DOES NOT retain these links to the old layer files -- they are simply loaded from the file, and the reference is not maintained.

Comment: If you are able to see the symbols in the TOC then you should be able to right click on the layer and do "Save as Layer file". Then apply that layer symbology back to the FC.